# Ajax Call with JS from Python

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I have simple django project name **Ajax** .And i installed only one app for this project name **Promocode** .
My problem in this project is Ajax call between js and python. I can't handle **Succes** with ajax call function . Error: function () result i got.
 I know i mistake in urls.py in promocode app and url mapping in ajax call function but i can't solve this. Please help me :)

**My main urls.py file is :**

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.conf.urls import url,include
import django.contrib.auth.views

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^', include('promocode.urls'))]
```

**My promocode app urls.py file is :**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
       url(r'^$', views.index,name='index'),
       url(r'^$', views.extract_json)]
```

**My views.py file is :**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import json
from suds.client import Client as Client
from django.http.response import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return render(request,'promocode/index.html')


def get_result_by_code(promocode):
    url = "http://service.emobile.az:8080/ws-loyalty-
    program/cp/loyaltyprogram.wsdl"
    client = Client(url)
    result = client.service.loyaltyProgramCalculate(
         amount=1000,
         authKey='testaede35740f2b9d2248b0ab6b878',
         identicalCode=promocode,
         terminalCode=2148)
    if str(result[2]) == "SUCCESS":
        status = 1
    else:
        status = 0
    return status


def extract_json(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    status = get_result_by_code(data['4545'])
    result = dict(
       status=status,
       message='Result Succesfully'
    )
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), mimetype='application/json')
```

**And my index.html file is :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Promocode Test </h3>

<label for="bakcelPromo">Promocode</label> <br>
<input type="text" name="bakcelPromo" id="bakcelPromo" class="form-control">
<br>
<br>
<label for="sum">Sum Insured</label> <br>
<input type="text" name="sum" id="sum" value="" class="form-control">

<p></p>

<button onclick="get_result_by_code();">Hesabla</button>

<br>
<br>
<label for="premium">Premium</label> <br>
<input id="premium" type="text" />
<br>
<br>

<script>
function get_result_by_code() {
var sum_insured = document.getElementById("sum").value * 0.035;
var promocode = document.getElementById("bakcelPromo").value;

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "promocode/" ,
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    data: { "promocode": promocode },
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.status == 1) {
            sum_insured = sum_insured * 0.8

        } else {
            sum_insured = sum_insured * 1.5
            }
        $('#output').html(response.message);

        },
        error: function () {
            alert('There was an error communicating with the server.');
        }
});
document.getElementById("premium").value = parseInt(sum_insured);
}  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First 2 urls with same regex patterns pointer to two different Views
second can you provide me with a screenshot to view to imagine what you want to do
Third Ajax url is not proper you can use url template tag `{% url "namespace:viewname" data %}`

Comment: Here is screen link :[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwGtk0EG74ekUmZUMVZ4TzVfcFU/view)  I input promocode and sum insured. This promocode send to python functions by js ajax and python function call a webservise and get result,1 or 0 . Then this result send back to js by ajax and at the end calculate premium on the base of returned result .Problem is on ajax call-back process . Can you update my wrote files above as correct and again write here please ?

Answer (score 0):

**My main urls.py file is :**

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.conf.urls import url,include
import django.contrib.auth.views

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^', include('promocode.urls'), namespace='appname')]
```

**My promocode app urls.py file is :**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
       url(r'^$', views.index,name='index'),
       url(r'^promo/$', views.extract_json, name='extract_json')]
```

**My views.py file is :**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import json
from suds.client import Client as Client
from django.http.response import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return render(request,'promocode/index.html')


def get_result_by_code(promocode):
    url = "http://service.emobile.az:8080/ws-loyalty-
    program/cp/loyaltyprogram.wsdl"
    client = Client(url)
    result = client.service.loyaltyProgramCalculate(
         amount=1000,
         authKey='testaede35740f2b9d2248b0ab6b878',
         identicalCode=promocode,
         terminalCode=2148)
    if str(result[2]) == "SUCCESS":
        status = 1
    else:
        status = 0
    return status


def extract_json(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        promocode = request.POST.get("promocode")
        status = get_result_by_code(promocode)
        result = dict(
           status=status,
           message='Result Succesfully'
        )
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), mimetype='application/json')
```

**And my index.html file is :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Promocode Test </h3>

<label for="bakcelPromo">Promocode</label> <br>
<input type="text" name="bakcelPromo" id="bakcelPromo" class="form-control">
<br>
<br>
<label for="sum">Sum Insured</label> <br>
<input type="text" name="sum" id="sum" value="" class="form-control">

<p></p>

<button onclick="get_result_by_code();">Hesabla</button>

<br>
<br>
<label for="premium">Premium</label> <br>
<input id="premium" type="text" />
<br>
<br>

<script>
function get_result_by_code() {
var sum_insured = document.getElementById("sum").value * 0.035;
var promocode = document.getElementById("bakcelPromo").value;

$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "{% url "appname:extract_json" %}" ,
    async: true,
    data: { "promocode": promocode },
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.status == 1) {
            sum_insured = sum_insured * 0.8

        } else {
            sum_insured = sum_insured * 1.5
            }
        $('#output').html(response.message);

        },
        error: function () {
            alert('There was an error communicating with the server.');
        }
});
document.getElementById("premium").value = parseInt(sum_insured);
}  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I got such error : **UnboundLocalError at /promo/**
**local variable 'result' referenced before assignment**

Comment: use `ipdb` to trace the code and know where is the error, I didn't run it I just delivered the idea. Copy Paste Ideology is not working

Comment: Understood, fixed this problem ,thanks  @A.Raouf

One more question ,how can i use ajax return value in my calculation ?
My ajax call function return value as result= {'status' :1 ,'message' : ....} 

 success: function (response) {
     if (response.status = 1) {
        data = $.parseJSON(result);
        data = data[0];
        if (data == 1) {
              sum_insured1 = sum_insured * 0.5  
             }
        else {
              sum_insured1 = sum_insured  * 2.0 }
             } 

Something like this or ?